# Android Linkify Special Phone Numbers

Tags: android, linkify

Hy! My TextView display string that consists of simple text, adresses, phone numbers, e-mail adresses and web urls. I am using Linkify and it works fine for e-mail adresses and web urls, but problem is with phone numbers because Linkify link me numbers from adresses, IDs and I want that it only link only phone numbers that start like this: "+385" and rest can be "021 348 600" for example. So I made regex but I dont know how to implment it into Linkify. Also I think my regex is OK. Here is my code:

```
MyTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvContact);
Spanned sp= Html.fromHtml( getString(R.string.huge_string_contact));
MyTextView.setText(sp);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("+385[0-9]");
Linkify.addLinks(MyTextView  , Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS | Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Answer (score 0):

That Regex wont do a thing. Try this.

```
Linkify.addLinks(MyTextView, Pattern.compile("385\\s\\d+\\s\\d+"),"");
```

Edit: Last parameter should be an Url scheme string. But we don't need that so it can be "".

Comment: I tried your code, but it gives me error: The method addLinks(TextView, Pattern, String) in the type Linkify is not applicable for the arguments (TextView, Pattern, int)

Comment: Still doesn't work, my phone numbera are now displayed as normal text.

Comment: Could you give me 2 examples of phone numbers starting with +385?

Comment: first:  ++385 021 348 600
second: ++385 021 668 043